# SQL: Output 0 when a count() has no rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following query

```
Select
    count(project.id) as '# Projects',
    c2.name as ' Country name'
from
    project,
    country c2,
    project_country
where
    project_country.project_id = project.id and
    project_country.country_id= c2.id
group by
    c2.name;
```

Which returns the number of projects related to a specific country only if the `count()>0`.

For the countries that don't have any project associated with I would want to get the **0** value in the **#Projects** column. Is there any way I can achieve this in **mysql**?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

**Solution with `IFNULL`:**

```
Select
    IFNULL(count(project.id),0) as '# Projects',
    c2.name as ' Country name'
from
    project,
    country c2,
    project_country
where
    project_country.project_id = project.id and
    project_country.country_id= c2.id
group by
    c2.name;
```

**Solution with `COALESCE`:**

```
Select
    COALESCE(count(project.id),0) as '# Projects',
    c2.name as ' Country name'
from
    project,
    country c2,
    project_country
where
    project_country.project_id = project.id and
    project_country.country_id= c2.id
group by
    c2.name;
```

Comment: Thanks @sebastianbrosch, but it doesn't seem to display 0 for the Countries that don;t have any related projects

Answer (score 1):

Please read a SQL tutorial, one which covers `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT
    C2.name AS `Country name`,
    COUNT(P.id) AS `# Projects`
FROM
    Project P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Project_Country PC ON PC.project_id = P.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Country C ON C.id = PC.country_id
GROUP BY
    C.name
```

The reason that you couldn't do it with your query is because you are using the old style of `JOIN`. By old, I mean circa 1994. That doesn't allow for `OUTER JOIN`s unless your RDBMS includes special syntax for it (like *=) and even then it's often confusing and hard to read.